# Detect if string contains any spaces

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I detect if a string has any whitespace characters?

The below only detects actual space characters. I need to check for any kind of whitespace.

```
if(str.indexOf(' ') >= 0){
    console.log("contains spaces");
}
```

Comment: What you have will detect any spaces characters, not just between words. But do you want to include other types of white space?

Comment: `console.log('  foo'.indexOf(' ') !== -1);` logs true for me, as does `console.log(' '.indexOf(' ') !== -1)`. `console.log(''.indexOf(' ') !== -1)` logs false, because an empty string doesn't contain spaces. Don't know what `s` holds for you, but `indexOf` should work

Comment: Only spaces between words? That's where spaces live.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell *exactly* what you're asking.

Comment: I want to detect if the string contains ANY white spaces.

Comment: @user971824: Ah, good. My answer actually does answer that, then. :-) (The top bit of the answer.)

Comment: What qualifies as a a whitespace character does differ - not only between contexts but also within concrete language versions of Javascript itself. Better make clear to which kind of Whitespace you actually relate to.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder This does work using a plain string directly on the if statement however I am using this on a password input and I'm currently trying to work out why this does not work when I'm passing the password string into my scope function.

Comment: @user971824: I'll keep an eye out for that follow-up question (I'm around for a bit). Do be sure to include the code (how you get the password value, how you pass it to "...[your] scope function...", and the code in that function that checks it).

Answer (score 135, accepted):

What you have will find a space *anywhere* in the string, not just between words.

If you want to find any kind of whitespace, you can use this, which uses a regular expression:

```
if (/\s/.test(str)) {
    // It has any kind of whitespace
}
```

`\s` means "any whitespace character" (spaces, tabs, vertical tabs, formfeeds, line breaks, etc.), and will find that character anywhere in the string.

[According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), `\s` is equivalent to: `[ \f\n\r\t\v​\u00a0\u1680​\u180e\u2000​\u2001\u2002​\u2003\u2004​\u2005\u2006​\u2007\u2008​\u2009\u200a​\u2028\u2029​​\u202f\u205f​\u3000]`.

---

For some reason, I originally read your question as "How do I see if a string contains **only** spaces?" and so I answered with the below. But as @CrazyTrain points out, that's not what the question says. I'll leave it, though, just in case...

If you mean literally spaces, a regex can do it:

```
if (/^ *$/.test(str)) {
    // It has only spaces, or is empty
}
```

That says: Match the beginning of the string (`^`) followed by zero or more space characters followed by the end of the string (`$`). Change the `*` to a `+` if you don't want to match an empty string.

If you mean whitespace as a general concept:

```
if (/^\s*$/.test(str)) {
    // It has only whitespace
}
```

That uses `\s` (whitespace) rather than the space, but is otherwise the same. (And again, change `*` to `+` if you don't want to match an empty string.)

Comment: This will also match empty string.

Comment: @HamZa: I was assuming that was desired.

Comment: T.J., that was really fast and straight forward!

Comment: Btw any documentation links for test() method? Please?

Comment: @abhishah901: [MDN is your friend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) (it's linked above). Or you can grab your safari hat and machete and delve into [the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-regexp.prototype.test), but it's a jungle in there, but this is one of the tamer parts of it.

Comment: if (/\s/.test(str)) { } is brining up all sorts of errors in visual studio.

Comment: @BKSpurgeon: It shouldn't, assuming you're editing a JavaScript file. That's a simple and valid statement.

Answer (score 4):

```
function hasSpaces(str) {
  if (str.indexOf(' ') !== -1) {
    return true
  } else {
    return false
  }
}
```

Comment: there is many white space which is not equivalent with white space that you just made with your space bar.

thus your code is not reliable.

Answer (score 1):

```
var inValid = new RegExp('^[_A-z0-9]{1,}$');
var value = "test string";
var k = inValid.test(value);
alert(k);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Answering questions is good but the purpose of this code is not clear. This answer would be much better if it inluded an explanation of what it does and how it answers the question. Please [edit] the answer.

Answer (score 1):

A secondary option would be to check otherwise, with not space (`\S`), using an expression similar to:

```
^\S+$
```

#### Test

```js
function has_any_spaces(regex, str) {
 if (regex.test(str) || str === '') {
  return false;
 }
 return true;
}

const expression = /^\S+$/g;
const string = 'foo  baz bar';

console.log(has_any_spaces(expression, string));
```

Here, we can for instance `push` strings without spaces into an array:

```js
const regex = /^\S+$/gm;
const str = `
foo
foo baz
bar
foo baz bar
abc
abc abc
abc abc abc
`;
let m, arr = [];

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
 // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
 if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
  regex.lastIndex++;
 }

 // Here, we push those strings without spaces in an array
 m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
  arr.push(match);
 });
}
console.log(arr);
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/XqDdCV/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/XqDdCV/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
var string  = 'hello world';
var arr = string.split(''); // converted the string to an array and then checked: 
if(arr[i] === ' '){
   console.log(i);
}
```

I know regex can do the trick too!