# Review setting up a rule in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a nameRules for my  where

```
v => (v && v.length <= 10) || 'Name must be less than 10 characters
```

but i want to change it so the user cannot add spaces so only one name is able to be input.

eg. user will be able to enter "bob" but not "bob smith".

I don't know if the code below is acceptable

```
v => (v != '') || 'Only first name'
```

i want the end result not to allow the user to add more than one name

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect if string contains any spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17616624/detect-if-string-contains-any-spaces)

Answer (score 0):

Here, just test for presence of a space in the name.

```js
const validName = name => {
   return name.length > 0 && name.length <= 10 && name.indexOf(' ') < 0;
};

console.log(validName("Paul"));
console.log(validName("Paul Thomas"));
```

Comment: [`includes(' ')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) is a bit more canonical than `indexOf(' ') < 0`