# How return false from with regex when string contains an empty space

Tags: javascript, regex

I have been trying to get the following regex to return false if the string has an empty space for the past 3 days. I have read about 24 Stack Overflow postings among other web resources. I've take 3 tutorials.

I have been able to return true when there's at least a number and a letter, and a string between 8 and 24 characters. I have not been able to return false when there is an empty space.

I know that `[^\S]` is supposed to solve the issue, but I haven't been able to get it to work.

Here's my function.

```js
function validatePassword(password) {
  const pattern = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])^(?=.*\s+$).{8,24}$/;
  return pattern.test(password);
}

console.log(validatePassword("AlmostBald1 2"));
```

I have read about 24 Stack Overflow postings among other web resources. I've take 3 tutorials.

I have been able to return true when there's at least a number and a letter, and a string between 8 and 24 characters. I have not been able to return false when there is an empty space.

I have tried adding this piece to my current regex pattern. Examples below:

```
const pattern = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])^(?=.*\s+$).{8,24}$/;
const pattern = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[^\S].{8,24}$/;
```

I have read (to name a few):

- https://regexone.com/lesson/excluding_characters
- [Detect if string contains any spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17616624/detect-if-string-contains-any-spaces)
- [Regular expression for not allowing spaces in the input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16334765/regular-expression-for-not-allowing-spaces-in-the-input-field)
- https://regex101.com/r/zG6Gbz/1
- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/validating-a-password-using-javascript

Comment: `\s` is space, `\S` is not space. `[^\S]` is...not-not space?

Comment: Do you have example strings that should test and should fail? Have you tested on a site like [Regex101](https://regex101.com)?

Comment: Your example code returns false, so what's wrong?

Comment: `.{8,24}` => `\S{8,24}`. `^(?=.*\s+$)` looks like a failed attempt, remove it if you do not require whitespace at the end of string.

Comment: If you're just trying to see if the string has a space, you could just simply throw in an if statement (if(password.indexOf(' '))...) to check if a space is present. Your regex appears to be checking several things, and you could just have the space check be separated out to simplify the regex.